# split to month and year variables

Tags: php, date

I have this code that will generate month and year from 2016 to 2017.

How do i simplify this code and separate it to two variables month and year ?

```
$start = $month = strtotime('2016-01-01');
$end = strtotime('2017-12-31');
while($month <=$end)
{
     echo date('F Y', $month), PHP_EOL;
     echo "<br />";
     $month = strtotime("+1 month", $month);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `date()` twice. Once for the year, once for the month.

```
$start = $month = strtotime('2016-01-01');
$end = strtotime('2017-12-31');
while($month <=$end)
{
     echo date('F', $month), ' ', date('Y', $month), PHP_EOL;
     echo "<br />";
     $month = strtotime("+1 month", $month);
}
```

Obviously you can change the formatting to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Having a love for Datetime, I would do:

```
<?php
  $date = new DateTime('2016-01-01');
  $enddate = new DateTime('2017-12-31');
  while($date < $enddate) {
    $month = $date->format('m');
    $year = $date->format('Y');
    echo $year .' '. $month . '<br>'.PHP_EOL;
    $date->modify('+1 Month');
  }
```